# Using grunt on windows

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I've installed grunt globally and and locally within my yeoman project but all grunt commands give the following error.  ANy idea how to get around this one?

```
c:\wip\code\project\yo>grunt -v
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

c:\wip\code\project\yo\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\file.js:372
  return fs.existsSync(filepath);
            ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'existsSync'
    at Object.exists (c:\wip\code\project\yo\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\fil
e.js:372:13)
    at Task.init (c:\wip\code\project\yo\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js
:417:31)
    at Object.tasks (c:\wip\code\project\yo\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt.js:1
13:8)
    at Object.cli (c:\wip\code\project\yo\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\cli.js
:38:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
grunt-cli\bin\grunt:41:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using node.js **v0.6** (as `fs.existsSync` got moved to `fs` in v0.8).

Grunt is only compatible with node.js `>= 0.8`.